# What's best module to built pie chart?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, charts

I want to build a pie chart to make a statistic for all my events. But, there are a lot of module. I want to know what's the best and responsive? I'm using drupal

Comment: Are you familiar with [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985)? And/or have you seen [this](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3614/39516)?Maybe you want more details about [this](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views)? Ps: "*using drupal*" is not really a surprise for questions posted around here, maybe *something* is missing at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart. It has support for both Drupal 7 & 8. I don't have a lot of experience with the module itself but I have used the Javascript library (http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) it uses and it is nice.